# jquery to find each child menu item and add a count to it

Tags: jquery, each

I have a menu which I want to prepend a numbered count to the link.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="parent" transform="100"><a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu"><span>Our Services</span> <span class="angle">/</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    <div class="child-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="parent" transform="200">
          <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">01 <span>Business &amp; Commercial Law</span> <span class="angle">/</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          <div class="child-menu">
            <ul>
              <li class="a-link-146"><a href="/"><span>Banking &amp; Finance</span></a></li>
              <li class="a-link-147"><a href="/"><span>Buying or Selling a Business</span></a></li>
              <li class="a-link-148"><a href="/"><span>Commercial Contracts &amp; Agreements</span></a></li>
              <li class="a-link-149"><a href="/"><span>Liquor Licensing</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="parent" transform="200">
          <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">02 <span>Debt Recovery &amp; Insolvency</span> <span class="angle">/</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          <div class="child-menu">
            <ul class="m-main-menu-child">
              <li class="a-link-150"><a href="/"><span>Debt Recovery</span></a></li>
              <li class="a-link-151"><a href="/"><span>Insolvency</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="a-link-129"><a href="/"><span>Careers</span></a></li>
  <li class="a-link-130"><a href="/"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>

$('.menu-content ul li.parent').each(function(){ // find each parent item
    $(this).find('.child-menu ul li a').prepend('*count*'); // for each child prepend the count
});
```

I've manually added in 01 and 02 in the above code where I want it to go..

Our Services
- **01** Business & Commercial Law
- **02** Debt Recovery & Insolvency

Hopefully this makes sense.. I've only managed to get it to prepend text before the links I want, I'm not sure how to make it do another loop to create the numbers before hand. There are multiple parent li's, I just grabbed a part of my code so you can read it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can retrieve the `index()` of the parent `li` and prepend that to the child `a` element. To format it as you require just needs some minor string manipulation to add a leading `0`. Try this:

```js
$('.menu-content > ul > li.parent > .child-menu > ul > li > a').prepend(function(i) {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
  return ('00' + (idx + 1)).slice(-2) + ' ';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class="parent" transform="100">
      <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">
        <span>Our Services</span>
        <span class="angle">/</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="child-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="parent" transform="200">
            <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">
              <span>Business &amp; Commercial Law</span>
              <span class="angle">/</span>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="child-menu">
              <ul>
                <li class="a-link-146"><a href="/"><span>Banking &amp; Finance</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-147"><a href="/"><span>Buying or Selling a Business</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-148"><a href="/"><span>Commercial Contracts &amp; Agreements</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-149"><a href="/"><span>Liquor Licensing</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="parent" transform="200">
            <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">
              <span>Debt Recovery &amp; Insolvency</span>
              <span class="angle">/</span>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="child-menu">
              <ul class="m-main-menu-child">
                <li class="a-link-150"><a href="/"><span>Debt Recovery</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-151"><a href="/"><span>Insolvency</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="a-link-129"><a href="/"><span>Careers</span></a></li>
    <li class="a-link-130"><a href="/"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    <li class="parent" transform="100">
      <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">
        <span>Our Services</span>
        <span class="angle">/</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="child-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="parent" transform="200">
            <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">
              <span>Business &amp; Commercial Law</span>
              <span class="angle">/</span>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="child-menu">
              <ul>
                <li class="a-link-146"><a href="/"><span>Banking &amp; Finance</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-147"><a href="/"><span>Buying or Selling a Business</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-148"><a href="/"><span>Commercial Contracts &amp; Agreements</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-149"><a href="/"><span>Liquor Licensing</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="parent" transform="200">
            <a href="/" class="js-open-child-menu">
              <span>Debt Recovery &amp; Insolvency</span>
              <span class="angle">/</span>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="child-menu">
              <ul class="m-main-menu-child">
                <li class="a-link-150"><a href="/"><span>Debt Recovery</span></a></li>
                <li class="a-link-151"><a href="/"><span>Insolvency</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a counter must helpful

```
var counter =0;

$('.menu-content ul li.parent').each(function(){ // find each parent item
    counter++;
    $(this).find('.child-menu ul li a').prepend(counter < 10 ? '0'+counter : counter); // for each child prepend the count
});
```